# Copy files with permission 200

Tags: permissions, cp

I want to recursively copy a directory, preserving file attributes, which contains a directory tree including some files that have permission 200 (i.e. `--w-------`).

The copy command `cp -ar sourcedirectory targetdirectory` skips those files, saying, for each one, something like this:

```
cp: cannot open `sourcedirectory/foo/somefile.bar' for reading: Permission denied`
```

**My question: without altering their permissions, how can I prevent the copy command from skipping those files?**

*If you think I ought to use a utility other than `cp` in my copy command, please explain why.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make the file readable in order to copy it. This is unrelated to the choice of tool: every program will fail to open the file for reading since you do not have the permission to read it.

If [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) are enabled (with ext2/ext3/ext4, this requires the mount option `acl`) and you aren't interested in copying them, add an ACL that allows the user doing the copy to read the file.

```
setfacl -R -m u:username:rX sourcedirectory
```

Otherwise, you'll have to either change the file permissions beforehand and restore them (on both sides) afterwards, or do the copy as root.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Migrating_data) gives a variety of ways to copy data, preserving as much metadata as possible. You could try each of these, *as root*:

- `cp -av /source /dest` # don't use `-r`, its behavior is hard to predict and `-a` already includes `-R`
- `cd /source; tar -cf- . | tar -xvpf- -C /dest`
- `cd /source; find . -depth -print0 | cpio -pdmv -0 /dest`
- `rsync -av --delete --hard-links /source/ /dest`

Rsync is a bit tricky about trailing `/`s in its arguments. As explained in its manpage, both of these are ways to copy the directory `/source/foo` to `/dest/foo`:

- `rsync ... /source/foo /dest`
- `rsync ... /source/foo/ /dest/foo`

Its possible that none of these will work. Make sure you try them while root for the best prospects.

Comment: Any of these methods will work, the key thing is **as root**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can think, we can follow these steps to maintain permission as it is and copy all the files also.

```
$ cd <sourcedirectory>

$ tar -cvf <sourcedirectory.tar> .

$ cp <sourcedirectory.tar> <destinationdirectory>

$ tar -xvf <sourcedirectory.tar>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the second step fails: `tar -cf sourcedirectory.tar .` gives messages like `tar: ./foo/somefile.bar: Cannot open: Permission denied`. (I have omitted the `-v` option to `tar`, but this should not affect the issue.)

Comment: It might work if you try it as root, but be sure to add the `-p` flag to the fourth line to preserve permissions when expanding, rather than using whatever your current `umask` is.